# Correcting SVN copy/move

Tags: svn

Another developer on the project moved a versioned folder without properly doing it via SVN. So SVN shows a directory tree deleted, and another one created, and doesn't show that one was simply the result of a rename of the other. This screws with peg revisions, difs, and source history.

Is there any way to fix this, for example via `svndump`?

Basically, to mark `trunk/b` as a copy-from `trunk/a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hand-edit the svndump file for that one commit to drop the content of all the additions and change it to a single addition of trunk/a with a copy-from and copy-from-rev.  Then you would need to dump all previous revisions and all following revisions, then load all the revisions in order into a new repository and replace your repository.  Then you need everyone to checkout from the new repository and trash their old working copies.

You can avoid the hand-editing bit, assuming the bad rename was the only thing in that commit.  Suppose the bad revision is $REV.  Dump revisions 0 up to (but not including) $REV.  Load those into a new repository.  Checkout from the new repository, do the correct rename, and commit.    Do an incremental dump of $REV+1 through HEAD in the old repository and load into the new repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can just branch from the version **before the modification**, do the right rename, then merge this to the trunk.
You will need to of course report modification from the 'new' directory during the merge.

This way, you have the history !

Or if the log has few revision, you can get a patch from its modification, **revert the modification into svn**, and modify by hand the patch to exclude the delete / create operations.